# Add reaction to a message (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I want to add a reaction to a message that gets send in one channel. I get the error code:

```
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.
```

Here is my code:

```py
client = discord.Client()

if message.channel.id == 737668230012862514:
    emoji = client.get_emoji(310177266011340803)
    await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line: `emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType` indicates that the `emoji` was set to `None`, meaning that the client could not find the emoji of id `310177266011340803`.

As you can see from the documentation, [`get_emoji`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_emoji) returns `None` if no emoji was found.

Please make sure that `310177266011340803` is a valid emoji id and that the bot has access to the server where the emoji is.

To access all emoji names and IDs, you can write:

```py
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    for emoji in client.emojis:
        print("Name:", emoji.name + ",", "ID:", emoji.id)
```

Comment: Are there any Emoji ID lists?