# I can't add reactions to a message in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Title. Here is my current code:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    emoji = client.get_emoji(765173945056886814)
    if message.author.id == 236199051505303552:
        await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

And the error i am getting is

```
line 1082, in _emoji_reaction
    raise InvalidArgument('emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not {.__class__.__name__}.'.format(emoji))
discord.errors.InvalidArgument: emoji argument must be str, Emoji, or Reaction not NoneType.
We have logged in as Zinthium#3381
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add reaction to a message (discord.py)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63137643/add-reaction-to-a-message-discord-py)

Comment: i wish it did; however, i do not know where to add the code and what to put in it, as i am very new to python. I hope you can clarify.

Comment: Your code doesnt work because it wants an Emoji that the API doesnt recognize.
The code in the linked answer helps you to get the ID of the Emoji you are looking for. Its Then you can input the correct emoji number

Comment: It says "expected an indented block" when i input the code.

Comment: I recommend you to try to learn more about python first. You need better understanding of the language itself before you can solve problems like this. Even with help.
What your error message means is that your code formatting is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

get the emoji code yourself on discord. by typing `\emoji`. `\`is basically the escape character in discord. emoji codes look like these `<:klol:716218157060325387>`

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == 236199051505303552:
        await message.add_reaction("emoji code")
```

Your code should actually work. I think the bot doesn't have access to that emoji. Maybe it is not in the server. So it returns `None`

Comment: i could do it, i needed to store the value manually.

Answer (score 0):

This

```
    emoji = ':woo:765172185995411456'
```

seems to have worked, i just need to label the emojis i'll use like emoji1, emoji2 and such, or emojiWoo.